# Mariadb: Access denied for user 'repl'@'xxx'- Replication slave permission getting revoked

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have 2 nodes running MySQL setup using Pacemaker.
Every time I standby the slave node and unstandby it later, it is not able to catch up and says the error as:

```
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'repl@masternode:3306' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Access denied for user 'repl'@'xx.xx.xxx.xx' (using password: YES)
```

Then I have to execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` on the master node, and execute the following on the slave node and it works fine.

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE ALL;
RESET MASTER;
SET GLOBAL gtid_slave_pos = '';
SET GLOBAL gtid_slave_pos = '10x-x-xxxx';
CHANGE MASTER to Master_Host = 'masternode', MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx', MASTER_PORT = 3306, MASTER_USE_GTID = current_pos;
START SLAVE;
```

I can see on the master node that the grant privileges are there, not sure why they don't work every time the slave node resets.

```
(mysql@masternode) [(none)] 13:12:37> show grants for 'repl'@'xx.xx.xxx.%';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for repl@xx.xx.xxx.%                                                                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'xx.xx.xxx.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I ensure that these permissions are not revoked or changed with the slave node dying or coming back.

Edit 1: Master and slave status

```
root@localhost) [(none)] 15:18:04> show master status \G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
            File: BINLOG.000001
        Position: 977
    Binlog_Do_DB:
Binlog_Ignore_DB:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


(root@localhost) [(none)] 14:22:29> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                   Master_Host: masternode
                   Master_User: repl
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: BINLOG.000001
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 325
                Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000001
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 4
         Relay_Master_Log_File: BINLOG.000001
              Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB:
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error:
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 325
               Relay_Log_Space: 256
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 1045
                 Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'repl@masternode:3306' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Access denied for $ser 'repl'@'xxx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error:
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 0
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos:
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: conservative
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: When it gets that Last_IO_Error, it will retry in 60 seconds. [MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/change-master-to/) can be used in `CHANGE MASTER` to a smaller value. Do you have a password longer than [41 characters (known bug - MDEV-23857)](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23857)?

Comment: No, the password is shorter than 41 characters. The whole setup was working fine till the slave node crashed and had to be rebuilt. I am sure I am missing something, but can’t figure out what.

Comment: Do you have sync_binlog=1? Is using the MASTER_{USER,PASSWORD} needed in the `CHANGE MASTER` statement? Which MariaDB version?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`` and `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`

Comment: @danblack- Yes, sync_binlog is set to 1. Yes, CHANGE MASTER needs the user and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; It was a different password for `'repl'@'localhost'` and `'repl'@'xx.xxx.xx.xx'`.

So while rebuilding the slave node, I had updated the password for `'repl'@'xx.xxx.xx.xx'`, but did not update the password for `'repl'@'localhost'`.

The pacemaker resource `mysql` was using the old `replication_passwd`, which was the reason why every time the slave node would restart, I had to issue the `CHANGE MASTER` command and include the replication username and password.

In the attempt to do this, I first update the pacemaker resource `mysql`, but that led to the master node shutting down as well and not able to start with the error as  access denied for `'repl'@'localhost'`. So, then I kept the original password, started master server and updated the password for `'repl'@'localhost'` and `'repl'@'xx.xxx.xx.xx'` both, stopped the master server and updated the password in pacemaker `mysql` resource as well.

It worked after that and restarting the slave node was also smooth.